# How can I use `String.substring` to set the start of my text string to be 5 characters before a `<span>` in a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I use this simple function below to set the *from* character and *to* character of `printItem.ArticleText`, but would like to set the *from* character to be 5 characters before a `<span>` (the `<span>` is in my text passed to the function).

```
angular.forEach(printArray, function(printItem){

    if (printItem.ArticleText === null) {
      summaryText = '';
    }
    else {
        summaryText = printItem.ArticleText.substring(10, 160) + '...';
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I totally understand what you are trying to achieve, could you give an example text? 

Is it something like this you want?
`var text = "dummy text<span>some more dummy text</span>";`
`text.substring(text.indexOf('<span>') - 5, text.length)` would yield:
`" text<span>some more dummy text</span>"`

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it :). Thank you.

Comment: May I ask another question in line with this question; How can i check whether my text passed does have a `<span>` in it? I have tried the following:    

`else if (printItem.ArticleText = indexOf('<span>')) {
            summaryText = '... ' + printItem.ArticleText.substring(indexOf('<span>'), 150)
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a start and end position dynamically you could use [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf).

Example:

```
var input = "dummy text<span>some more dummy text</span>";
var output = input.substring(input.indexOf('<span>') - 5, input.length)
```

Result:

```
" text<span>some more dummy text</span>"
```

To check whether or not the input string has `<span>` we could do the following:

```
var input = "dummy text<span>some more dummy text</span>";
var output = "";

if (input.indexOf('<span>') !== -1) {
    // <span> is present in input string.
    output = input.substring(input.indexOf('<span>') - 5, input.length);
} else {
    // <span> is not present in input string,  
    output = input;
}
```